# Save Excel spreadsheet file without the password

Tags: excel, perl, win32ole

I am trying to open password protected excel and save it with no password.
I know the password. When I am trying to run the code below, the file is being saved with the password.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings,

use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel *';

my $file = "in.xls";
my $outFile = "out.xls";

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new ('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
$Excel->{'Visible'} = 0;    #0 is hidden, 1 is visible
$Excel->{'DisplayAlerts'} = 0;  #0 is hide alerts

my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open({FileName => "$file", Password => 'test'});
my $Sheet = $Book->Worksheets('test');
$Sheet->Activate();
$Book->SaveAs({Filename=>"$outFile",FileFormat=>xlWorkbookNormal});
$Excel->Quit();
```

Please advise.

Thank you,
-Andrey

Comment: Copying the whole `$sheet` to a new `$Book` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

```
$Book->SaveAs({Filename=>"$outFile",FileFormat=>xlWorkbookNormal, Password => undef});
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$Book->Unprotect('test'); # Where 'test' is your password
```

Reference: [Workbook.Unprotect Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196695.aspx)